# Magento 2 Catalog Price Rule issue

Tags: magento2, catalog, catalog-price-rules

```
php bin/magento indexer:status
```

When I add a new catalog price rule from admin. The offer price could not be reflected in the front-end. then I check the indexing options. all indexing are UPDATE ON SHEDULE. How can i get the updated price on frond-end with out reindexing?

I have checked the indexer:status shown below. Please check and help me.

```
+----------------------------------------------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Title                                              | Status | Update On | Schedule Status     | Schedule Updated    |
+----------------------------------------------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Amasty Product Label                               | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 07:55:41 |
| Amasty Product Label                               | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:06:51 |
| Amasty Related Products                            | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:06:52 |
| Amasty Related Products                            | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (6 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 07:55:41 |
| Amasty Reports                                     | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (6 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 07:55:41 |
| Amasty Reports                                     | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:06:52 |
| Amasty: Advanced Search  - Categories              | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:05:59 |
| Amasty: ElasticSearch - Popup Data                 | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:06:36 |
| Amasty: ElasticSearch - Relevance Rules (Products) | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (6 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 07:55:37 |
| Amasty: ElasticSearch - Relevance Rules (Rules)    | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:06:30 |
| Amasty: Product Grid - Qty Sold                    | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:06:52 |
| Catalog Product Rule                               | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (5 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 09:53:08 |
| Catalog Rule Product                               | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:05:34 |
| Catalog Search                                     | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:06:30 |
| Category Products                                  | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:05:28 |
| Customer Grid                                      | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:05:26 |
| Design Config Grid                                 | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:05:25 |
| Inventory                                          | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:05:41 |
| Product Categories                                 | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (2 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 09:53:08 |
| Product EAV                                        | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:05:39 |
| Product Price                                      | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:05:59 |
| Stock                                              | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-05-27 10:05:41 |
+----------------------------------------------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: i think run cron command

Comment: */5 * * * * /sbin/relax php -f /chroot/home/bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogrule_product i have added this cammand in crontab. after that nothing happened price was same.